# Electromagnetic waves in tensor notation

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, covariance

I'm trying to derive the wave equations for the electric and magnetic fields in [covariant (tensor) formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Maxwell%27s_equations_in_vacuum).
Starting with Gauss-Ampere law,
$$
\partial_\alpha F^{\alpha\beta}=\frac{4\pi}{c}J^\beta
$$
and Gauss–Faraday law
$$
\partial_{\alpha}(\tfrac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}F_{\gamma\delta}) = 0
$$
I would like to derive the values of $\square \vec{E}$ and $\square\vec{B}$, or in general get to $\partial^{\nu} \partial_{\nu}  F^{\alpha\beta}$. Is there an elegant way to do this? I did try using summation in each of the equations, but got quite confused with all the indices.

Comment: Do you want the wave equations in vacuum? So with $J^\beta=0$? Or do you want the wave equation for inside materials?

Comment: Preferably inside material, which is more general (so I can plug in $J^\beta=0$ afterwards to get them in vacuum).

Comment: Try simplifying $\partial^\alpha ( \partial_\alpha F_{\beta\gamma} + \partial_\gamma F_{\alpha\beta} + \partial_\beta F_{\gamma \alpha} ) = 0$. The thing in the bracket is the Bianchi identity (or Gauss-Faraday law).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Lorentz gauge your first equation becomes the wave equation for the potential
$$
\partial_\alpha \partial^\alpha A^\beta = \frac{4\pi}{c}J^\beta ~.
$$
By deriving left and right hand side you obtain
$$
\partial_\alpha \partial^\alpha F^{\gamma\beta} = \frac{4\pi}{c} \left(\partial^\gamma J^\beta - \partial^\beta J^\gamma \right) ~,
$$
which is the required wave equation.